# Firebase getDatabase() не создает id для новых записей

Tags: vue.js, firebase

Я добавляю новуб категорию в имеющуюся базу

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set} from "firebase/database";

export default {
    actions: {
        async createCategory({commit, dispatch}, {title, limit}) {
            try {
                const uid = await dispatch('getUid')
                const category = await set(ref(getDatabase(),`/users/${uid}/categories/`), {title, limit})
                // return {title, limit, id: category.key}
                }
            catch (e) {
                commit('setError', e)
                throw e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но в конечном итоге, я не получаю уникальной записи и все мои послледующие попытки добавить новую запись, перезаписывают имеющуюся. Я хочу получать записи с уникальным id как для пользователей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите в чем причина?